# Dúvida sobre query (agrupamento)

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma tabela chamada `ALUNO_LEGADO` no SGBD SQL Server conforme abaixo:

[image: Tabela para mostrar o conceito obtido pelo aluno nas disciplinas cursadas]

Supondo que existam apenas 5 disciplinas (`1,2,3,4,5`) e os conceitos sejam `A = Aprovado` e `R = Reprovado`, qual condição utilizo para buscar apenas os `RA`'s que possuam reprovação em **todas** as 5 disciplinas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo a seguinte estrutura

```
create table aluno_legado
( 
   ra          varchar(03),
   disciplina  int,
   conceito    varchar(01)
);

insert into aluno_legado(ra, disciplina, conceito) values
('ra1', 1, 'R'),
('ra1', 2, 'R'),
('ra1', 3, 'R'),
('ra1', 4, 'R'),
('ra1', 5, 'R'),
('ra2', 1, 'R'),
('ra2', 2, 'R'),
('ra2', 3, 'R'),
('ra2', 4, 'R'),
('ra2', 5, 'A'),
('ra3', 1, 'R'),
('ra3', 2, 'R'),
('ra3', 3, 'R'),
('ra3', 4, 'R');
```

Supondo que existem apenas 5 disciplinas, a seguinte query irá produzir o resultado que pretendes

```
select ra
from   aluno_legado
group by ra
having count(distinct case when conceito = 'R' then disciplina end) = 5;
```

Esta query devolve os RA que têm o número de disciplinas únicas/distintas com conceito = 'R' igual a 5.

Vê o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7199c/1)

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, funcionou